# How to check if no two lines containing the same strings in VIM

Tags: vim, find, pattern-matching

I would like to know how am I gonna be able to check if in my 1000 lines txt-file, no two lines have the same pattern. in the third section, namely, "CF.Name" i.e. I have something like :

```
 APPNAME            NO  CF.Name
 automotive_bitcount 1 -funsafe-math-optimizations -fno-guess-branch-probability    
 automotive_bitcount 1  -fno-guess-branch-probability   -fno-inline-functions -funroll-all-loops -O2 
 security_blowfish_e 2 -funsafe-math-optimizations  -fno-ivopts    -O2
 security_blowfish_e 2 -funsafe-math-optimizations  -fno-ivopts -fno-tree-loop-optimize  -funroll-all-loops -O2
```

and so on. Just wanna make sure all the generated CF.Name are different from each other.

Answer (score 3):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has a `:PrintDuplicateLinesIgnoring` command that searches for duplicate content in lines while skipping over certain parts. In your example, you want to ignore the first two sections, which can be matched by *start of line, some non-whitespace, some whitespace, some non-whitespace, some whitespace*. Ergo:

```
:PrintDuplicateLinesIgnoring /^\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+/
```

Note: This still won't find lines where the same arguments are given in a different order; hopefully, your creation process ensures that, or you'll have to sort the arguments first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you know always which plugin to take for vim, this is the second time ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Delete all columns except the one you want to check, then `:sort u`.  If the result is 1000 lines, then you know that no two lines have the same pattern in that section.

Comment: thanks for the reply, if that wasn't zero, how to point out the faulty ones after sort ?

Comment: I suppose that after deleting the other columns you could first `:sort`, then copy into another buffer and `:sort u` on that that.  Then you could `:diffthis` on each buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I would take parts of the other answers:  use `:sort` as in @Jeff's answer, but use a pattern as in @Ingo Karkat's answer instead of deleting the other columns:

```
:sort /^\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+/
```

Now for something new:  a multi-line pattern.  If you want to find two consecutive lines that are identical, use `/^\(.*\)\n\1$`.  If you care about the third column (delimited by whitespace) then search for

```
/\v^\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*\n\S+\s+\S+\s+\zs\1\S@!
```

For variety, I have used the `\v` ("very magic") variant.  (This way the `+` and `@!` do not need to be preceded by `\`.)  Also, I slipped in `\zs` ("start here") so that you highlight only the interesting part.